# Tensorflow- I'm getting those labels, is that expected?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have the following convolutional neural network (CNN), but wasn't trained on many  images. In this CNN, I'm entering an image and trying to see what label would the model return. The model returned two labels for the two images added. The labels were `[1 1]`, while I was expecting them to be `[0 0]`. But, since I didn't train a lot of images, is that expected?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cifar_tools
import tensorflow as tf

learning_rate = 0.001

data = cifar_tools.read_data()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 150 * 150])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 64]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 64, 64]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))

w3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([38*38*64, 1024]))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]))

w_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, 2]))
b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))

def conv_layer(x,w,b):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x,w,strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')
    conv_with_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv,b)
    conv_out = tf.nn.relu(conv_with_b)
    return conv_out

def maxpool_layer(conv,k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(conv, ksize=[1,k,k,1], strides=[1,k,k,1], padding='SAME')

def model():
    x_reshaped = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 150, 150, 1])

    conv_out1 = conv_layer(x_reshaped, w1, b1)
    maxpool_out1 = maxpool_layer(conv_out1)
    norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(maxpool_out1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)
    conv_out2 = conv_layer(norm1, w2, b2)
    norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv_out2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)
    maxpool_out2 = maxpool_layer(norm2)

    maxpool_reshaped = tf.reshape(maxpool_out2, [-1, w3.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    local = tf.add(tf.matmul(maxpool_reshaped, w3), b3)
    local_out = tf.nn.relu(local)

    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(local_out, w_out), b_out)
    return out

model_op = model()

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(model_op, y))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

res_model=tf.argmax(model_op, 1) # testing
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(model_op, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred,tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    batch_size = len(data)
    # Save model
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    # Restore model
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\\Testing\\mymodel.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    tf.add_to_collection("vars", w1)
    tf.add_to_collection("vars", b1)
    all_vars = tf.get_collection('vars')
    for v in all_vars:
        v_ = sess.run(v)

    print('model restored')

    # Test on unlabeled data
    for i in range(0, len(data), batch_size):
        new_data = data[i:i+batch_size, :] #testing
        res_new = sess.run(res_model, feed_dict={x: new_data})
        print('LABEL IS')
        print(res_new)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you train your network on a lot of data, having two misclassified images in your test set is not unexpected. So in general, I don't think that you can infer much when you consider only two test cases. You should definitely increase the amount of your test images to be able to assess the performance of your network.

Keep in mind that even before you start training, you could get by random correct classification for some images. Recall that your weight matrices are initialized randomly. So if you have 2 classes and you apply your untrained network, probably around 50% of your images will be classified correctly by random (and 50% will not).

In addition, depending on the type of images that you use and other factors, you may need more data to be able to train the network well enough. You can read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127111/how-much-data-do-you-need-for-a-convolutional-neural-network) some discussion about how to determine if you have enough training data.